# An additional view overlay the main view

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit

I have a main view where there are buttons and google map.

```
let maps = MapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapview = maps

        view.addSubview(mapview!)
```

And by changing the state of the user, details are added to the main view in the same way.

```
let new = ButtonView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        ButView = new
        view.addSubview(ButView!)
```

When adding these views, my map is overlapped by layers of additional views and I cannot do any actions. Because the extra view all overlaps, how to avoid it?

```
class ButtonView: UIView {
    var FromButton : MainButton = MainButton()
    var toButton : MainButton = MainButton()
    var Send : MainButton = MainButton()



    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(Send)
        addSubview(FromButton)
        addSubview(toButton)
        addview()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    }
```

Comment: Try this `view.bringSubview(toFront: ButView)`

Comment: i can't see the added view , i update my code , and show how i add views

Comment: When creating your ButtonView you give it a frame which is as big as the view you're adding it to. Try with a small width and smaller height!

`ButtonView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))` instead of `view.frame.width` and `view.frame.height`

Comment: Please provide some screenshots so that it would be more clear.